# Is it possible for different dynamic memory addresses to share the same offset value?

Tags: pe, memory, game-hacking, cheat-engine

I am currently using cheat engine to hack a game. I used the pointer scanner to find some pointers to the pistol ammo memory location. I then went to look for pointers to the shotgun ammo memory location, which obviously is at a different address. Looking at the offset for the shotgun memory location it says is the same offset as the pistol ammo. How can I do a pointer scan for a memory location that has the same offset as another location in memory? I tried running a pointer scan to the shotgun ammo memory location using the same offset as the pistol ammo and it found nothing.

Comment: Moving onto another weapons ammo, it also uses the same offset. So it seems that all the ammo for this game appears to be using the same offset. I'm not sure what is happening.

Comment: Maybe ammo is some kind of array or struct and the access is base (the pointer) x index?